# How to add inline images and attach files in Java mail

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

I am using the Java mail API for e-mailing. I have to e-mail a message that contains both inline images specified by HTML's `<img>` tag and some attached files.

What content type I should use for `MimeMultipart` that contains the parts for inline images and attachment files?

```
MimeMultipart multipartInline = new MimeMultipart(?);
```

Comment: MimeMultipart multipartInline = new MimeMultipart(?); what type should i place in.

Answer (score 5):

There's three different types of multipart content to consider here:

- multipart/mixed - commonly used to contain the main message body with
  "attachments"
- multipart/alternative - used to send the same data in
  different formats, e.g., plain text and html
- multipart/related -
  commonly used to contain an html body part and the images referenced
  by that html

You can nest these different types in all sorts of interesting ways.

To answer the original question, you want a message with this structure:

```
main message
  multipart/mixed
    multipart/related
      text/html - main html content
      image/jpg - an image referenced by the html
    application/pdf - or whatever, for the first attachment
```

The html part will want to reference the image part using a "cid:" URL reference,
and the image part will need a corresponding Content-ID header.
[RFC2387](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2387.txt) has more details.  You can probably find some examples by searching
the [JavaMail forum](https://forums.oracle.com/forums/forum.jspa?forumID=975).

Comment: +1 , thanks for this very clear and understandable explanation.

Answer (score 0):

You must use one or two headers for each attach:

If it's a normal attach:

- Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=...

If it's an inline attach (image for your mail)

- Content-Disposition: inline
- Content-ID: *arbitrary-id*

This is extracted for a small sending program I've programmed some time ago:

`bodyPart` is a `MimeBodyPart`.

```
bodyPart.setHeader("Content-Disposition", disp + "; filename=" + encodedFileName);
bodyPart.setHeader("Content-Transfer-Encoding", "base64");
if (att.getContextId() != null && att.getContextId().length() > 0)
    bodyPart.setHeader("Content-ID", "<" +  att.getContextId() + ">");
```

In it: disp has `inline` or `attachment`, and `att.getContextId()` has some arbitrary ID for the inlined attach.

**My recipe for an HTML mail**

```
message has via .setContent(...)
    mainMultipart is a MimeMultiPart("alternative")
                  and has via .addBodyPart(...)
        textBodyPart is a MimeBodyPart with content-type "text/plain"
        relatedMultipart is a MimeMultipart("related")
                         and has via .addBodyPart(...)
            htmlBodyPart "text/html; charset=utf-8"
            INLINED-ATTACH1
            INLINED-ATTACH2
        NORMAL-ATTACH1
        NORMAL-ATTACH2
```

Comment: Ups, I've realized you want to know the type for the containing part... I'll edit my answer.

Comment: Note that the mainmultipart has a "text-version" and an "html version". Your text version can be empty if you want. After that, the normal attach are added to the main part, while the inline attachs are added to the related-multipart (the html one). It's a structure I've learnt some time ago when I had to program a general mail sender.